# How to post href by JavaScript or jQuery non AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to post data to a PHP file by link.
I'm using this:

```
<a onclick="$.post('responses.php', {'form':'<?php echo $_GET['form'] ?>'});return false;" href="#">
```

This code works but I want to post data to and brows response.php then I need a non AJAX equivalent code.

Comment: Why non-AJAX? Then how would you send the request?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like form should be good for your case:

```
<form method="post" action="responses.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="form" value="<?php echo $_GET['form'] ?>'});return false;"/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

This code will both post data and redirect user to response.php as you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want an AJAX thing, you can do the same thing using a form:

```js
$(function () {
  $("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.bleh.submit();
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="bleh" class="hidden" target="ifr" method="post" action="responses.php">
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<iframe name="ifr" class="hidden"></iframe>
<a href="#">Click to Submit</a>
```